# Calculates MTD reset by new year

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have this values by month, we need to calculate the cumulative values by month but group by year.
I can´t reset cumulative by year.

```
Acum = CALCULATE(
                SUM('Clientes historico'[Medidor abierto]); DATESMTD(Mes[Mes ID]))
```

[image]

See te picture.

[image]

Comment: can you post a shot of your data model?

Comment: Do you mean YTD instead of MTD? TOTALYTD or DATESYTD

Comment: @mixx Just try this, but the problem is when I stay on January, and not reset de acumulated value. on January mi value -1440